# JList.getModel() ClassCastException

Tags: java, swing, jlist

When I call `JList<String>.getModel()` and cast it to `DefaultListModel<String>` it gives me this exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$4 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel
```

The code that throws it:

```
private JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
((DefaultListModel<String>) list.getModel()).addElement(...);
```

It doesn't do it every time though. Most of the time it works perfectly, but other times it throws this exception. I don't understand why this is happening. Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: For what its worth I thought the question was reasonable and complete, though this could be because of andrew's edits.

Comment: @ditkin I can't even tell what Andrew edited. But I found the problem, it was calling the method `setListData(E[])` changed the `ListModel` of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not assume it is a DefaultListModel.  Use the interface ListModel.
The JList is returning an internal implementation of ListModel.

If you need access to the underlying model you should create it, set it in the JList constructor and retain it yourself.

Comment: retaining it is not necessary! see nikola despotoski's answer it is much more efficient!

Answer (score 16):

I experienced this issue. I found this simple workaround:

```
//----instantiation----

    JList mList = new JList();
    mList.setModel(new DefaultListModel());

    /*---- do whatever you want---- */

    //Retain it wherever you want with
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)mList.getModel();
```

Comment: I had the same problem... Creating it with a new default list model fixes everything. +1

Answer (score 10):

If you are using NetBeans

1. Select your *jList*
2. In *properties*, click the *model* button
3. select the "*Custom code*" option
4. Write `new DefaultListModel ()`

[image: jList custom code]

Answer (score 1):

Before `JList<String>.getModel(),` you must initialize your object `JList<String>.setModel(new DefaultModelList())`

Comment: nothing new compared to one of the earlier answers, is there ;-)