# Getting casting exception from DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list2.getModel();

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove a item from a jListBox on java 9
I keep getting a exception saying

```
ClassCastException: java.desktop/javax.swing.JList$1 cannot be cast to java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListModel
```

when I call
      DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list2.getModel();

Program
..

```
    String[]  selections = { "green", "red", "orange", "dark blue" };
    JList list = new JList(names);
    list.setSelectedIndex(1);

    ListModel  model = list.getModel();
```

The exception goes oiff here

```
((DefaultListModel) model).removeElement(0);
```

..
..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JList.getModel() ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375115/jlist-getmodel-classcastexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
int selectedIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
if (selectedIndex != -1) {
    model.remove(selectedIndex);
}
```

or in your particular case

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();
model.removeElement(0);
```